# extract the last 2 bits in binary

Tags: java, binary, bit

The number 254 is 11111110 in binary. My problem is I want to grab the last 2 bits (10). I was told to use the % operator to do this but I don't know how. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: How do you want to "grab" them? You want to obtain a `String` "10" or a number "2"?

Comment: I need to write the method so that the following in main will be correct:

    result = getLeastSignificant2(255);

    System.out.println( "The result of getLeastSignificant2(255) is " + result );

    if ( result == 3 ) {

      System.out.println( "This is correct!" );
    }else {
      System.out.println( "This is WRONG!  Should be 3" );
    }

Answer (score 5):

Supposing you want to get the numeric value of the last 2 binary digits, we can use a mask.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 0b1110;
    int mask = 0b11;
    System.out.println(n & mask);
}
```

What the code is doing is taking the number, in this case `0b1110` and doing an `and` with the mask defined `0b11`.

`0b` is how you tell java that you are expressing the number as binary.

In case you wanted to obtain the binary number as binary, you can use this:
`Integer.toBinaryString(n & mask)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use % to convert to binary but I believe its easier to use Integer.toBinaryString() and then charAt() to get the last 2 characters like they do in here
[How do you get the last character of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163785/how-do-you-get-the-last-character-of-a-string)

Comment: Can you help me? Why when I mask the negating bit and shift it I get a negative value. eg: 10000000 | 00000000  | 00000000 | 00000000. Here I have an int with the negating bit on. If I shift it to the right. { 00000000 | 00000000 | 00000000 | 00000001 } and mask that one bit I get -1. In.Cpp I would get 1.

Answer (score 2):

The last two bits can be obtained by doing `x % 4`, or by doing `x & 3`.

`x % 4` is remainder after division by `4`, which is a number `0`-`3`, as represented by the last two bits.

`x & 3` is a bit-wise AND operation with the binary number `11`, i.e. zero'ing all other bits.

The second is generally the fastest at runtime, and the preferred method for doing bit manipulation. *(Use a bit-wise operator for bit manipulation, right?)*

Comment: x & 3 only works for 255, but what if I wanted to get the last 2 bits of 64?

Comment: @dye `64 & 3 == 0`.  `64` (decimal) is `01000000` (binary), and the last 2 bits are `00`. Which part confused you?