# How to return the last character of a string in Python?

Tags: python

How can I get the last character of this string?

```
seed_name = "Cocoa"
```

Comment: [Slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/5472354): `seed_name[-1]`.

Comment: @mapf But it's *not* slicing, but indexing. (yes, `[-1]` appears in the answer over there but technically it shouldn't)

Comment: @mkrieger1 fair enough. I always felt like indexing is just a subset of slicing.

Comment: Relevant meta question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374701/what-to-do-when-the-question-is-so-trivial-rtfm-that-it-doesnt-even-have-a-prop

Comment: @BhargavRao https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163785/how-do-i-get-the-last-character-of-a-string is Java, not Python; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478127/remove-final-character-from-string "remove the last character" is something else than "return [or get] the last character".

Comment: I also don't think "[-1]" can be an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/how-do-i-get-a-substring-of-a-string-in-python while it is *the* answer here

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As shown in the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings),

> ```
> >>> word = 'Python'
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Indices may also be negative numbers, to start counting from the right:
>
> ```
> >>> word[-1]  # last character
> 'n'
> ```